# Given a directed graph, can you determine if it can be drawn as a planar graph?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, directed-graphs

Say a directed graph has loops and has nodes directed towards each other.

I would like to know if there is an algorithm for determining if the graph can be drawn as a planar graph.

Comment: Why does it matter that the graph is directed? Isn’t this just the same as if you forget the directions of the edges and asking whether the resulting undirected graph is planar? I may not understand the definitions you are using here

Comment: Like Nick wrote, the directedness of the graph seems irrelevant, and Kuratowski's Theorem states that a (finite) graph is planar iff it does not contain a subgraph that is a subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.

Comment: To simplify matters a little, the first steps of your algorithm should be to remove any loops (i.e., any edges connecting a node to itself) and then remove any nodes of degree $2$ (i.e., nodes having exactly two edges) by joining the two edges into one.. Once you have done that, see if it contains either $K_5$ (a set of $5$ nodes each pair of which are connected by an edge) or $K_{3,3}$ (two sets of $3$ nodes such that each node in one set is connected to every node of the other set) as a subgraph. If so, it is not planar. If not, it is planar.

Comment: Actually, you will also need to remove all duplicate edges (any two edges with the same two endpoints, regardless of direction) leaving only a single edge remaining, and then remove each degree $1$ node and its connecting edge, including nodes that become degree $1$ by other removals, before identifying and removing all degree $2$ nodes.